# Page number at a different position on every page. How to force it to the same format

Tags: page-numbering

I've got a problem with the page numbering in my document. First, it was in the middle of the footer of the first page (as now), then to the left in the header of the second, and then on the right side of the header of the third page. Then, when I added some text in the header the page numbers of page 2 and 3 disappeared. I've tried different strategies in order to define one single position, e.g. trying different styles, title page environment, and fancyhdr. Would really appreciate some help!

```
    \documentclass[twoside,twocolumn, 12pt]{article}

    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage[square,numbers,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnatnodoi}
    \usepackage{natbib,epsfig,endnotes}
    \setlength\parindent{0pt}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{gensymb}
    \usepackage{textgreek}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{times}
    % \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    % \pagestyle{fancy}
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \usepackage{graphicx, subcaption, setspace, booktabs}

    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{longtable}

    \usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \linespread{1.05}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
    \widowpenalty10000
    \clubpenalty10000

    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[hmargin=20mm,top=20mm,columnsep=12pt]{geometry} 
    \newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}



    %\renewenvironment{titlepage}
        %{%
          %\if@twocolumn
            %\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
          %\else
            %\@restonecolfalse\newpage
          %\fi
         % \thispagestyle{empty}% remove the empty page style
          %\setcounter{page}\z@ %remove the counter reset
        %}%
    %\makeatother

    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Fig. \thefigure}
    \makeatother

    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
    \pagestyle{fancy} % All pages have headers and footers
    \fancyhead{} % Blank out the default header
    \fancyfoot{} % Blank out the default footer
    \fancyhead[C]{\small Concept Plan $\bullet$ December 2018} 

    \usepackage{titling} 

    \usepackage{hyperref} 


    \begin{document}
    \title{ \vspace*{2\baselineskip} 
            \large \textsc{\today}
            \\ [2.0cm]
            \HRule{0.5pt} \\
            \LARGE \uppercase{\textbf{Concept Plan}\\ Title}
            \HRule{0.5pt} \\[0.5cm]
            \vspace*{2\baselineskip}}

    \date{}

    \author{
            person and info}


    \clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
    \maketitle
    \newpage



    \vspace{-3\baselineskip}
    \textbf{State of the Art}

    \blindtext

    \newpage

    \bibliography{references}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you cleared the header/footer under the `fancy` page style. You probably need

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{\small Concept Plan $\bullet$ December 2018}
\fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Note that the first page will still be set in `plain` with `\maketitle`, which has the page number in the centre of the footer by default. To change this to match your `fancy` page style (that is, have it set in the right header, since the first page is odd), add

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. This will set the `plain` page style to be equivalent to `fancy`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion using page style `fancyplain` provided by package `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{} % clear default header and footer content
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% page number on both plain and fancy pages
\fancyhead[C]{\fancyplain{}{\small Concept Plan $\bullet$ December 2018}}% header only on fancy pages

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\date{}
\author{person and info}
\maketitle

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]